# Why is group and aggregate is faster for a Series than for a one column DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When group by and aggregate is called on a pandas.Series, it is faster than calling on a pandas.DataFrame with one column (which is a pandas.Series instance). Below is an example:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import time

column1 = [random.randint(1,3) for i in range(1000)]
column2 = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]


df = pd.DataFrame(zip(column1, column2), columns=["group", "number"])

t1 = time.time()
grouped_1 = df.groupby("group").sum()
t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)


t1 = time.time()
grouped_2 = df.groupby("group")["number"].sum()
t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)

print("First type %s" %type(grouped_1))
print("Second type %s" %type(grouped_2))
```

Output =

```
0.0062596797943115234
0.0024614334106445312
First type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Second type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

What is the bottleneck for aggregating a dataframe with one column vs a series?